# How to deploy a template-file with c#

Tags: c#, debugging, resources

I need to provide a template file (templateA.xls|templateB.xls) which users can edit and then will be used by the c# application.

When deployed the structure will look like:

```
AppFolder+
         +-App.exe
         +-Templates+
                    +-templateA.xls
                    +-templateB.xls
```

As in my solution the files are arranged in this way:

```
Solution+
        +-App+
             +-Resources+
                        +-Templates+
                                   +-templateA.xls
                                   +-templateB.xls
```

I want to access from the App.exe with the following call:
`Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) /Templates/templateA.xls`
I've choosen following options on the files:

```
Build Action = Resource, 
Copy To Output Directory = Copy always
```

But now `\bin\Debug\Resources\Templates`is empty. I can copy the files manual but this is not how it should be. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you select Resource as Build Action, the resource will be included in the exe as a resource. You should select **Content** as Build Action instead.